# Django migrations or Python or VSCode problem

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

i want to migrate model but terminal in VSCode just prints out 'Python'
i use VSCode and terminal is powershell

the picture is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3tpu.png)

what should i do to solve this problem?

Comment: please provide full image. Is the path of project correct?

Comment: You should add some more description

Comment: Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You are required to provide sample input and corresponding output along with your coding attempt.

Comment: Haven't used Python on Windows for a decade, but I guess the capital `P` is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows cmd to do so. Try the command there. First goto command prompt. After opening the command prompt, goto your project directory. E.g, if your project directory name is myDir and it is present in a folder myMainFolder,  then in command prompt write this command

`cd myMainFolder/myDir`

Then there run the command

`python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: Hi. thank you for your kind answer but it failed. it just prints out "Python"

Comment: can you please upload some more details

Comment: i deleted python and django project folder after all.. and reinstall them so it has solved. and i enter 'python manage~' instead of 'python3 manage~' though i installed python3.9.1 verison. thank you for your help and if you know why i should use 'python' please leave a comment. have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if your default terminal type is PowerShell, you may see an error that it cannot run activate.ps1 because running scripts is disabled on the system. use Terminal: Select Default Shell to set "Command Prompt".

Comment: Hi. thank you for your answer but it failed. it just prints out "Python"..